# use a bird to write with

Tags: to-infinitive

In this [movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88_Ailmf8Z4), starting at 41 seconds, Maui says:

> When you use a bird **to write with**, it's called tweeting.

Does the to-infinitive clause modify "a bird"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it tells you more about the bird the speakers is talking about. It's not just any old bird, it's a special kind of bird. Specifically, one that's used for writing or one that you use to write things with.

This type of structure is similar in principle to the fallowing examples:

> She is a force **to be reckoned with**. (you would not want to make that woman upset or else you're going to have problems)
>   He's not a guy **to be messed around with**. (you would not want to mess around with that guy)
>   There is nothing **to be ashamed of**. (you should not be ashamed of it)
>   There is nothing **to be worried about**. (you should not be worried about it)

Comment: Thanks. May I ask one more question? If you want the to-infinitive clause to modify not "bird" but "use", how can you rewrite the to-infinitive clause? For example, does this work? "When you use a bird **to write with it**, it's called tweeting."

Comment: I think it's better to say "When you use a bird to write things with, it's called tweeting".

Comment: So, just adding "things" can make the clause modify "use" instead of "bird"? I mean, I wonder how "to write things with" cannot be viewed as modifying "bird" as well.